# Is there an installer for geodict python library?

Tags: text, location, geo

I wanted to use the code:

```
import geodict_lib
locations = geodict_lib.find_locations_in_text(text)
```

But there seems to be no installer for geodict_lib. How do I install this is Anaconda 3.0 Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year on, but perhaps I could help others who stumble on this. You'll need to place the files in the directory for modules that your installation of Python is monitoring.

1. First, download the .zip file from GitHub [here](https://github.com/petewarden/geodict).
2. Once you've done that, you can run the following at the command line or terminal:

   conda list
3. This will provide the path to all installed packages in your installation of Python. Move the geodict.zip file you downloaded to that location. You might want to run `which python` as well (see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125825/how-do-i-know-which-python-install-is-being-used)) since you may have a few different installations to check for.
4. Now when you run `python import geodict` in Python it should run without trouble!